How to vertically align items in beamer footer using minipage?
I'm struggling to get three elements in the footer to align vertically properly. I'm using minipage for layout, but regardless of the alignment settings (top, center, bottom - see images below), they never align correctly. Here's the relevant part of my LaTeX code:
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5em,dp=1ex]{footline}
        \hspace*{1em} % Horizontal space for padding from the left edge
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.15\paperwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=1cm]{lorem-ipsum-logo.png}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.4\paperwidth}
            \flushleft
            \usebeamerfont{footline}\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
            \scriptsize
            lorem.ipsum GmbH \\
            \tiny
            Loremstr. 44, 53121 Lonn \\
            info@lorem.ipsum
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.35\paperwidth}
            \flushright
            \scriptsize
            LoroBoost\\
            Version 1.0
        \end{minipage}
        \hspace*{1em} % Right padding for symmetry
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

The logo on the left, address in the middle, and version on the right do not align vertically. Could someone suggest a way to improve the alignment? Perhaps there's an alternative to minipage or a different approach within minipage?




How do you want your items to be aligned? Vertically centred?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Assuming you want the content of the footline to be vertically centred, you could use the following code. If you prefer the minipages to be top or bottom aligned, adjust the height and depth of them beamercolorbox as needed.
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{footline}{bg=lightgray}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.6cm,dp=0.5cm,leftskip=1em,rightskip=1em]{footline}
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{.15\paperwidth}
            \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-duck}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{.4\paperwidth}
            \flushleft
            \usebeamerfont{footline}\usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
            \scriptsize
            lorem.ipsum GmbH 
            
            \tiny
            Loremstr. 44, 53121 Lonn 
            
            info@lorem.ipsum
         
        \end{minipage}%
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[c][1cm]{.4\paperwidth}
            \flushright
            \scriptsize
            LoroBoost
            
            Version 1.0
            
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}



(Comment to OP): The most important one is remembering to adjust ht and dp in beamercolorbox as needed. If one just uses [b] in the minipages in this example, it looks horrible until ht and dp is adjusted accordingly

ok. that seems to work. thanks.  (used .35 \paperwidth for the last minipage to avoid linebreak)
Is there also a way to add some whitespace below the colorbox or is this a nontrivial task? (\vspace is not doing the trick)

@mcExchange vspace works fine to add space below the footline. If it doesn't work for you, ask a question and show what you tried.

@mcExchange If you got a line break: did you remove your manual spaces \hspace*{1em}?

true. it works for the footline. Just for the frametitle it's causing an issue. Maybe I make a separte question for this. or google around some more...
